# function to separate columns

Tags: php, function

This is my friendship table:

[image: mysqli relationship table]

How can I query removing my own id? I'm user_id = 1
How can I print my friends? (2, 3 and 5)

```
$showFriends = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `relationship` WHERE (`user1_id` = '$user_id' OR `user2_id` = '$user_id') AND `status` = 1") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    if($showFriends->num_rows > 0) {
        while($f = $showFriends->fetch_assoc()) {
            foreach(($f !== $user_id) as $como) {
                $como = $f;
            }
        }
        echo $como;
    } else {
        echo "You have no friends!";
    }
```

Kinda blocked now :(

Comment: `WHERE user1_id != MY_ID AND user2_id != MY_ID`?

Comment: have you attempted anything? Are you wanting to return that csv as a mysql result, or through formatting in php?

Comment: @Darren probably the right idea, but that specifically would not work.

Comment: Darren it can't be that way because I can be in either column.. Maybe I should think to alter the table. Make an new one...

Comment: Don't post your code in a comment. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42058601/edit) your question and put your code there.

Comment: @Sean I know ;P we aren't a charity here haha (*was purely pseudo code*)

Comment: Done! Sorry :)
Gotta keep that in mind

Comment: @Ruth How do you define the relationship? Does user1 always add user2?

Comment: Darren not true.. Simply don't know how to do it. If you wanna check my code you can see the project in http://dicasparaapostas.com

Comment: Darren, saw this here:
http://www.codedodle.com/2014/12/social-network-friends-database.html

Comment: @Darren, doing pseduo code is completely valid, but it should be a plausible example.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your logic. You only need to check if `if($como != $user_id)`.

Try something like -

```
$showFriends = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM relationship WHERE (user1_id = '$user_id' OR user2_id = '$user_id') AND status = 1") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
if($showFriends->num_rows > 0) { 
    while($f = $showFriends->fetch_assoc()) { 
        foreach($f as $como) { 
            if($como != $user_id){
                echo $como;
            } 
        }
}
else { 
    echo "You have no friends!";
}
```

---

we assume that you have properly sanitized `$user_id` to prevent sql injection. If not, make sure to visit [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Well I only do this to sanitize data:
$id = strip_tags(htmlentities(htmlspecialchars($id)));
Not sure what SQL Injection is..